# Expression<Func<>> only valid inline and not through bound lambda in Moq's Setup()?

Tags: c#, recursion, lambda, moq, expression-trees

The mocking library [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) has a Setup() method with the signature:

```
public ISetup<T, TResult> Setup<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
```

So I can do something like this just fine (using the library's recursive mocking):

```
Mock<Thing> _thing = new Mock<Thing>();
_thing.Setup((Thing t) => t.PropA.SubPropB).Returns(string.Empty);
```

But this fails:

```
Expression<Func<Thing, object>> test = (Thing t) => t.PropA.SubPropB;
_thing.Setup(test).Returns(string.Empty);
```

with the error:

```
Expression is not a method invocation: t => (Object)t.PropA.SubPropB
```

What's the difference between the inlined lambda and the one assigned to a variable first? Aren't both *expression trees* and not yet compiled (Moq parses the tree)?

Edit - Looks like the issue is with the `Func<Thing, object>` typing. Why is, e.g., `string` acceptable, but `object` is not?

Comment: Because `System.String` is not covariant with `System.Object`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is, e.g., string acceptable, but object is not?

because function declaration in `moq` is not covariant by generic types. Try to Setup moq in next way

```
 _thing.Setup(test).Returns((object)string.Empty);
```

because you have next signature `Expression<Func<Thing, object>>` and it's not covariant with respect to `object`

Or change your signature to `string` like this (assume `t.PropA.SubPropB` returns string):

```
Expression<Func<Thing, string>> test = (Thing t) => t.PropA.SubPropB;
                        //^here should be string
```

**Real-case**
I have created a test project with `Expression` as local variable, it all works fine with `string` and `object`. Please check my configuration if I missed something. **Moq** - 4.0.10827v

```
[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Mock<Thing> _thing = new Mock<Thing>();

        Expression<Func<Thing, string>> setup = t => t.PropA.SubPropB;
//                               ^ works with string and object
        _thing.Setup(setup).Returns(string.Empty);

        Assert.IsEmpty(_thing.Object.PropA.SubPropB);

    }
}

public class Thing
{
    public virtual Thingy PropA { get; set; }
}

public class Thingy
{
    public virtual string SubPropB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to define some general type for something like: `List<Func<Thing, object>> things = ... { new Func<Thing, int>(), new Func<Thing, string>(), ... }`. The `(object)` cast in the `Returns()` had no effect with the `object` generic type; same error.

Comment: @wes I have updated my answer, please check it if any mistakes made